# Flutter FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0xfd (at offset 52)

Tags: android, flutter

When I tried to run my flutter app in Vs Code.I'm getting this error.In my recent app everything worked fine.In this app only thing I've done just adding the firebase connection.In flutter doctor there is no error and no turkish chracter used.

Comment: No turkish eh? ¥

Comment: My native language.Non english chracters used.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. It's because I've build flutter folder in the program files. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your own question when figuring out the solution on your own!